# Why is Var or RADIUS invalid for a typename (identifier) in C++?

Tags: c++, identifier

**Situation:**
I'm learning C++ whth a book and theres an excercise to dertemine whether an identifier/typename is valid or not.

My mistakes were that the following identifier/typename I said to be valid.

a) RADUIS 
b) Var

**What i did afterwards:** 
I checked if they are reserved, but they're not.

**Question:**
Why are RADIUS and Var not allowed to use them as identifiers ?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mre] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Who told you, that they are invalid identifier names? It [compiles successfully](https://wandbox.org/permlink/cX9L44W9RysxQfqf).

Comment: There is likely some missing context that renders them invalid as there is nothing in the language that forbids them.

Comment: There is a list of identifiers. 

a) z
b) 14okt
c) ende
d) mat.nr
e) eingabedatum
f) c2356
g) ws94/95
h) ausgabe-vektor
i) zero
j) x_achse
k) RADIUS
l) Var

According to Solution These are valid: a),c),e),f),i),j)

that means also that RADIUS and Var are invalid.

Comment: @limonade What book are you using?

Comment: I could imagine the author wants to force a variable style, where you aren't allowed to name a variable with a starting upper case letter.

Comment: Book: C/C++ für Studium und Beruf, link: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-658-18581-7

Comment: If we talk about books, is https://www.learncpp.com/ reliable ? It covers a lot of topics I need. But I have no experience with it but it is rated (on a website) as a good tutorial.

Comment: If you are not required to use that book, I would sugges getting [one of these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  C/C++ is not a language so even that books title would make me want to throw it away.

Comment: Ok I read the lines in the book. Seems clearly wrong to me

Comment: Thanks, I should change that book.

Comment: @limonade There are no known good online C++ tutorials.

Comment: The problem is that in my university they do not provide a Skript. 
I failed on the test last summer and now I'll have the exam in Winter and according to my question it is clear that I'm a beginner. :( So I'm looking for something where I can learn cpp good.

Comment: I won't go as far as molbdnilo, but the vast majority of C++ tutorials do suck. This is in line with [Sturgeon's Revelation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturgeon%27s_law) and should be expected. As a result, unless you know enough of the language, usually from [reading books of good pedigree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), to be able to identify bad tutorials, you're probably going to find and learn from bad tutorials.

Answer (score -2):

The book quotes:

> C/C++-Konvention (nicht zwingend)
>
> Üblicherweise schreibt man Variablen- und Funktionsnamen in Kleinbuchstaben,
> symbolische Konstanten dagegen in Großbuchstaben

English:

> C/C++ Convention (not forced):
>
> In general, variables and functions are written with lower-case letters,
> symbolic constants on the other hand with upper-case letters

So the author wants to force his recommended style in this question, which is asked really bad, because he only asks which identifiers are valid, not which are "good"

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: Not so sure about this being due to the rule. If you look at the supposed answers for the following question number 4, where you are supposed to identify "self-defined names" in a code sample, it says that only `prod` is one, while the sample contains a declaration `int a, b, prod;`. So `a` and `b` should clearly be included as well. The answer to question number 5 ("write a program printing [...]") contains `#include <iostreamh>` [sic!]. I think they were just sloppy in writing out the answers.

Comment: Or sloppy and using TurboC++.